# UICollectionView with UITextView very slow

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView, with custom UICollectionViewCell.
Every cell has a UITextView inside.
The problem: the UICollectionView is very slow, also in the simulator.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[self.collectionView registerClass:[AgendaCollectionCell class]
         forCellWithReuseIdentifier:agendaCellIdentifier];
}
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


 AgendaCollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:agendaCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.delegate = self;
cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
[cell setCurrentDateAtIndex:([indexPath row]) date:currentMonth events:events];


// Return the cell
return cell;
```

}

I checked the profiler

[image]

Every cell makes date-related computations.
As you can see, the loadNibNamed takes too much time to load. Also the UITextView takes too much.
I searched a lot of question here and used some of their answers.(I also cached all instances of NSCalendar). I do not understand why it takes about 435 ms to load. The UICollectionView has 40 cell (it contains the days of a month).
Should I abandon the use of UICollectionView and cast to a custom view by using drawRect?

**EDIT**
I think that a good point is that suggested in the answer: load the cell by using UNib and not registerClass. I can see a very big performance boost: from 400ms to just 98ms!

Answer (score 1):

Try putting

```
UINib * nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"YourNibName" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.collectionView registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
```

into your `viewDidLoad` and then never create the cells yourself (in the

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

implementation always call

```
UICollectionViewCell * cell = [collectionView dequeueCell...]
```

This way, I think, the `collection view` will only load the nib once (in your `viewDidLoad` method and then create copies of it when needed.

Comment: Actually, in my viewDidLoad I have  [self.collectionView registerClass:[AgendaCollectionCell class]
             forCellWithReuseIdentifier:agendaCellIdentifier]; and the dequeCell in cellForItem

Comment: Oh, I see you are loading the nib in `initWithFrame`. I myself would not do that precisely for this reason - you can't give control over the loading to the `collectionView`, for example. Maybe consider turning it around, registering the nib, putting the custom class into the nib and loading it just once? So I suppose your designated initialiser would be `initWithCoder:` then, not `initWithFrame`.

Comment: I do not understand, sorry. I edited the code. Could you explain your comment?

Comment: Oh, I see. Never mind then. I would just still recommend trying to register the nib (load the nib once) instead of registering the class and thus loading the nib x times, x being the number of cells that are visible at the same time + ~ 3.

Comment: Pardon, but where shall I register the custom cell? It is registered inside the viewDidLoad of the class where I make use of cellForItem...

Comment: Yes, you are using `registerClass`, but I would recommend using `registerNib` (as I have shown in my answer). When you register the class (in which you are loading the nib), you need to load the same nib many times. If you registered the nib (not the class), you could only load it once.

Comment: I may have missed something, but why aren't you just using prototype cells within the UICollectionView in the storyboard?

Comment: Yes, that is an option too, but it would require redoing the nib file in the Storyboard (totally worth it though).

Comment: There is still a problem: I cannot get the gestures recognizer set for every cell if I use the UNib method...:(

Comment: Why? You are still in control of the collectionView:cellForIndexPath: method. There you can always setup anything you want on the cells, even gesture recognizers.